# NodeJS / MongoDB - Avoid wrong current time saving by mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, ubuntu, mongoose

I want to check if a record is expired after 30 minutes.
I do it like this:

```
if (orderBlocked.createdAt + (30 * 60 * 1000) > Date.now())
```

My orderBlocked model looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userBlockedSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    attemp: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Number,
        default: Date.now()
    },
});

const VerificationClass = mongoose.model('OrderBlocked', userBlockedSchema);

module.exports = VerificationClass;
```

The `orderBlocked.createdAt` field is equal to the time when I restarted the server for the last time. Why does the field has the same value and doesn't update? I console logged both `Date.now()`.

```
console.log(Date.now(), orderBlocked.createdAt);
```

Immediately after the  `console.log` ran I looked up the times this is the result:

`Date.now()`: (date) 17:41:25 **this is the right value**

`orderBlocked.createdAt`: (date) 15:08:37

Like you can see the `orderBlocked.createdAt` is almost 2 hours and 30 minutes less than the `Date.now()`, they were both runned on the same moment.

**IMPORTANT:**

I'm running this application on a `nginx` server using `ubuntu`.

What am I doing wrong, I can't find any related topics to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set default value for `created_at`, you used `Date.now()`.

That is actually function execution which returns a value, and that value is set as default.
As that code executes when you run your app(restart server), that time will be used as default value.

You want to pass function reference as default value (mongoose knows that it should execute it every time to get default value).

Replace this line:

```
default: Date.now()
```

with this one:

```
default: Date.now
```

Read more about mongoose defaults here:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html